# How does a developer send and receive multiple requests with multiple div's using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have  built a page where I send an Ajax post request to a php and also get a response using below.

```
    <input type="hidden" id="qid" value ="2" /> 

  <div id="scores"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">


setInterval(loaddata, 1000);

function loaddata()
{

 var qid=document.getElementById( "qid" );

 if(qid)
 {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'data.php',
  data: {
      qid:qid.value
  },
 
  success: function (response) {
   // We get the element having id of display_info and put the response inside it
   $( '#scores' ).html(response);
 
  }
  });
 }
  
 else
 {

 }
}
</script>
```

This works for sending one request and receiving a response.

Now I'm trying to sending multiple requests as below

```
  <input type="hidden" id="qid[]" value ="2" />     <input type="hidden" id="qid[]" value ="3" />
```

Now I want to catch responses for the multiple requests I have sent and display them in their divs respectively like below

```
    <div id="scores"></div>

<div id="scores1"></div>
```

and in my php

```
<?php

foreach ($var as $new)
{
// send response back for each ID
}
?>
```

and in my updated Ajax below see the success method where I want to collect the multiple responses and send them to their respective divs

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    
    
    setInterval(loaddata, 1000);
    
    function loaddata()
    {
    
     var qid=document.getElementById( "qid" );
    
     if(qid)
     {
      $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'data.php',
      data: {
          qid:qid.value
      },
     
      success: function (response) {
       // We get the element having id of display_info and put the response inside it
       $( '#scores' ).html(response);
    $( '#scores1' ).html(response);
     
      }
      });
     }
      
     else
     {
  
     }
    }
    </script>
```

e.g response for "2" goes to `{scores}` and response for "3" goes to `{scores1}`

Please help on how to go about this final part

Comment: Please add more of the HTML involved  - there is almost certainly a cleaner way to do this without resorting to ID attributes

Comment: sorry that was supposed to be a name attribute, I am unable to edit my question @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: e.g.   <input type="hidden" id="qid" name="qid[]" value ="2" /> .   <input type="hidden" id="qids" name="qid[]" value ="3" />

Comment: If there are multiple input elements whose values are to be sent to the server in a single request then it makes sense to send structured data back from the server (json) - it is frustrating that the question is in a locked state, I should have edited it rather than approve last edit.

Comment: a js fiddle of urs could do or just make an answer, also I have no issues in returning the data, my question definitely would be how do I target both divs using their separate ids?

Comment: what does `data.php` do and what does it return? Do the values of the hidden inputs change over time - if so, how?

Comment: data.php is where the posted data goes to and then I used that data to query a database and there is a result

Answer (score 1):

For an unlimited (?) number of input elements and their respective output DIV elements sending and returning structured data to/from the server enables you to associate the initial value with the returned response. The below removes the ID attributes and uses dataset attributes instead (personal preference)

```
<?php
    /**********************************************************************
        Consider that this PHP is data.php
        The ajax request is sent here and somehow it is processed - database
        lookups are done and data is processed. Structured data is prepared
        and sent back as JSON.
        
        This demo ONLY emulates the final pat where data is sent back....
        the data here is nonsense JSON data but KEYED with the data-attribute
        found on the input element which refers to the target DIV element.
        
        The AJAX callback looks for an element with that KEY (data-name) and
        writes output to that element.
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['sources'] ) ){
        $output=[];
        
        $sources=json_decode( $_POST['sources'] );
        foreach( $sources as $receiver => $value ){
            $output[ $receiver ]=array(
                'sql'       =>  'select x from y',
                'result'    =>  mt_rand(0,1),
                'code'      =>  uniqid(),
                'time'      =>  time(),
                'value'     =>  $value
            );
            sleep( 0.1 );
        }
        
        
        exit( json_encode( $output ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
        <input class='source-data' type='hidden' data-receiver='output-1' value='2' />
        <input class='source-data' type='hidden' data-receiver='output-2' value='8' /> 
        <input class='source-data' type='hidden' data-receiver='output-3' value='16' /> 
        <input class='source-data' type='hidden' data-receiver='output-4' value='52' />
        <input class='source-data' type='hidden' data-receiver='output-5' value='8' />
        <input class='source-data' type='hidden' data-receiver='output-6' value='2' />
        <input class='source-data' type='hidden' data-receiver='output-7' value='40' />
        <input class='source-data' type='hidden' data-receiver='output-8' value='17' />
        <input class='source-data' type='hidden' data-receiver='output-9' value='1' />
        <input class='source-data' type='hidden' data-receiver='output-10' value='68' />


        <div data-name='output-1'></div>
        <div data-name='output-4'></div>
        <div data-name='output-2'></div>
        <div data-name='output-3'></div>
        <div data-name='output-5'></div>
        <div data-name='output-9'></div>
        <div data-name='output-10'></div>
        <div data-name='output-8'></div>
        <div data-name='output-6'></div>
        <div data-name='output-7'></div>


        <script>

            const t=5;
            
            const mt_rand=function(a,b){//generate number between low & high values.
                return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( b - a + 1 ) + a );
            };
            
            setInterval(()=>{
            
                let source={};
                document.querySelectorAll('.source-data').forEach(input=>{
                    source[ input.dataset.receiver ]=Number( input.value );
                    
                    // for demo only, update values so that it appears the user has somehow modified stuff.
                    input.value = Number( input.value ) + mt_rand(1,100);
                });
                
                let fd=new FormData();
                    fd.set('sources', JSON.stringify(source) );
                
                let endpoint=document.location.href;    //  data.php
                
                fetch( endpoint,{ method:'post',body:fd } )
                    .then( r=>r.json() )
                    .then( json=>{
                    
                        Object.keys( source ).forEach(key=>{
                            let div=document.querySelector('div[data-name="'+key+'"]');
                            if( json.hasOwnProperty( key ) && div!=null )div.innerHTML=Object.keys( json[ key ] ).map( k=>[k,json[key][k]].join('=') ).join(', ')
                        })
                    })
                
            }, 1000 * t );
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```